# menuItem conditional rendering of item with boolean value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a menuItem component with two items from mui (verion 0), I need to add a condition. When data is loaded if the status is failed the download btn should be greyed out.
below is the menuItems

```
const buildMenuItems = (resource) => {
  return [
    <MenuItem primaryText='File Details' key='detail' value={`/security/log-history/${resource.id}/detail`} />,
    <MenuItem primaryText='Download File' key='download' value={`/security/log-history/${resource.id}/download`} disabled={true}/>
  ]
}
```

The menuItem component gets imported into log page where a table shows all the logs.

```
const columns = [
  { title: 'Created', prop: 'created_at', format: 'dateWithTime' },
  { title: 'File Name', prop: 'csv_file_name' },
  { title: 'Uploaded by', prop: 'user_name', sortable: false },
  { title: 'Upload Status', prop: 'status' }
]
```

The 4th column with prop of status, shows the status of the uploaded file either successful or failed statuses. If the file was successful, the menu should allow the user to download the csv file and if not successful the download link in the menu should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` and `useEffect` to track the changed of `status` and set the `menuItem`'s disabled state accordingly:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

...............

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "successful") {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
    if (status === "failed") {
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [status]);


...................

<MenuItem primaryText='Download File' key='download' value={`/security/log-history/${resource.id}/download`} disabled={disabled}/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think react hooks is supported by the react version i am currently on. V15.4.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a const called failed, resource has a property of status. if status is failed the download link should be disabled.

```
const failed = resource.status === 'failed'

  return [
    <MenuItem primaryText='File Details' key='detail' value={`/security/log-history/${resource.id}/detail`} />,
    <MenuItem primaryText='Download File' key='download' value={`/security/log-history/${resource.id}/download`} disabled={failed}/>
  ]
```